# Finding an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ with the dot product, find an orthonormal basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ such that:

$\textrm{Span}\left\{e_1\right\}=\textrm{Span}\left\{\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)\right\}$

and $\textrm{Span}\left\{e_1,e_2\right\}=\left(\textrm{Span}\left\{\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ -\frac{2}{5} \\ \frac{1}{5} \end{array}\right)\right\}\right)^\perp$

How should I approach this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the span of $e_1$, you can choose to let
\begin{equation}
e_1 = \left(\begin{matrix} 1\\ 0\\ 0\end{matrix}\right).
\end{equation}
Then we're told that the span of $e_1$ and $e_2$ is orthogonal to (the span of) a particular vector.  But the span of $e_1$ and $e_2$ must also be orthogonal to the span of $e_3$, so why not let $e_3$ be a unit length vector pointing in the direction of
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{matrix} 0\\ -\frac{2}{5}\\ \frac{1}{5}\end{matrix}\right)?
\end{equation}
In fact, this vector *is* unit length, so just set
\begin{equation}
e_3=\left(\begin{matrix} 0\\ -\frac{2}{5}\\ \frac{1}{5}\end{matrix}\right).
\end{equation}
Finally, $e_2$ needs to be orthogonal to both $e_1$ and $e_3$, and it needs to have unit length.  Do you know how to find a vector which is orthogonal to two given vectors?  Once you have such a vector, can you scale it to make it unit length?

Comment: So we need to look for $<e_1,(x,y,z)>=0$ and $<e_3,(x,y,z)>=0$?

Comment: Yes.  Are you familiar with the cross product of two vectors?